# How to split Rent-a-Room scheme tax exemptions with joint owners

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law

My brother and I bought a house together. I own 60% and he owns 40% (this is on the deeds). I live in the house and he does not. I have two lodgers living with me, who pay rent.

Typically one is allowed £7500 tax free lodger income if you live in the house. If you are joint owners you are supposed to split this 50-50 (£3750 each). Hence I would be eligible for £3750 income tax free, and my brother will be eligible for £0 tax free since he does not live in the house. But would we be able to split it 60-40, since we are 60-40 joint owners?

Comment: Skimming [the help sheet](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rent-a-room-for-traders-hs223-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs223-rent-a-room-scheme-2017--2) I'd guess no, to keep it simple. But you can probably just [call HMRC and ask](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/income-tax-enquiries-for-individuals-pensioners-and-employees#phone-title)?